# PHP: PDO MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't really know MySQL but I try.

I have this script in PHP

```
$sql = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ($this->firstname, $this->lastname, $this->email, $this->password))");
```

and when I use

```
print_r($sql->errorInfo());
```

It is giving me this error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: no parameters were bound in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.27-0\apache2\htdocs\OOPLogin\register.php on
>   line 115 Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )

If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you.

EDIT: I changed it to

```
$sql = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ($this->firstname, $this->lastname, $this->email, $this->password))");
```

And now it's giving me

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, ff0b80f26259f9c0178aeed5198bac48))' at line 1 )

Comment: Count parameter of `column` and `value` of insert query

Comment: You are missing one parameter (`5` against `4`).

Comment: You are missing "id" value. You could try NULL or not declaring it after INTO clause in case its a AUTO_INCREMENT column

Comment: Best question title ever. You win.

Comment: The second problem is because you are missing the ' in the values or you could use prepared statements binds tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `prepare()` function.  When using prepared statements, you are supposed to use either `?` or `:name` as placeholders for your values.  This prevents you from constructing a malicious SQL query from user input.

Also, you are listing 5 fields, but only give 4 values.  If `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field then it can just be omitted from the query.

Finally, you had too many `)` in your query,

```
$sql = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`)
    VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password)");
```

Now you just pass an array of values to `execute()` to bind to the placeholders.

```
$sql->execute(array(
    'firstname' => $this->firstname,
    'lastname' => $this->lastname,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'password' => $this->password
));
```

P.S. Your original code didn't work because you forgot to put quotes around your strings.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`email`) VALUE ('test@example.com');
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your using PDO, you need to bind parameters with a prepared statement.

Here's an example, using the [`PDO::prepare` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for reference:

```
$statement = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`) VALUES (?)");

$statement->execute(array($user_id));
```

Additional example using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as an alternative...

```
$statement = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`) VALUES (?)");

$statement->bind_param("i", $user_id);

$statement->execute();
```

You need to bind each of your parameters instead of putting them inline your prepared statement.

Comment: Yep, youre correct, I've added an additional example.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID-column does not have a corresponding value to insert, if that column is auto-incrementint you can skip it, like so:

```
$sql = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ($this->firstname, $this->lastname, $this->email, $this->password))");
```

you need as many values to insert, as you have columns

Comment: You're right, I was using the phpMyAdmin generated on and forgot about that.

But now it's giving me another error.

Comment: Now it's giving me
> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, ff0b80f26259f9c0178aeed5198bac48))' at line 1 )

Answer (score -1):

An Insert query need to have the same parameters in table fields and values in the same order.

So, if you have `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`
you need to have `idValue`, `firstnameValue`, `lastnameValue`, `emailValue`, `passwordValue`

A good way to try if query is well formed is do an `echo $sql` or a `var_dump($sql)` and paste the result on a sql ID query like Mysql Workbench or HeidiSql